# Development of mozilla add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am very new to mozilla add-on development. And finding its very difficult to quickly startup.

I am looking for a boilerplate of basic mozilla add-on.

With following:

```
live-reload  : for any change in files, to automatically create new xpi and automatically install in firefox
configuration : some constant values like version no, name etc, i can use in html files and in js files. (if i change any one should automatically update everywhere)
debugging : if i add console.log to anywhere, should print on terminal or console of browser
distributing : to automatically concat and minify the source code, and prepare xpi file for the same
```

The very good example i can take of http://meanjs.org for web development

is there anything similar for firefox add-on development

Answer (score 0):

The [addon-sdk](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) provides APIs for configuration and its module system can be used for declaring constants once, it provides a [tool for project setup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29), debugging is already [built into the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox), concatting and minifying the source is unnecessary, the SDK has a module system which allows modules to be loaded on demand and thus reduce the startup overhead.

I strongly recommend exploding [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons), most answers are there if you just look.